# How can I beautify camera like Beauty Plus camera in livekit_client in flutter?

Tags: webrtc, livekit

I have implemented live streaming app like Bigo using LiveKit streaming engine in flutter. But no idea how to filters camera in livekit_client. Please help me. Thanks.

There is no way to filters camera to beautify video in livekit_client. I've no idea is this possible or not.